# Download all files from firebase storage using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, firebase, firebase-storage

I am working on a project where the user uploads images into firebase storage and i want to retrieve all those images and store locally.

Using [pyrebase](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase) i can manage to download a single image(if i know the filename or download URL)

```
storage = firebase.storage()
storage.child("images/example.jpg").download("img")
```

But in my situation i may not know what is the name or download URL of file is. Pyrebase only supports to download single file and the filename should also be known.

Is there an alternative way to list / download all the files from firebase storage? Code snippet would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Here the file names are in 1,2,3,.... format. Here you have to add the json account also, by downloading it from firebase settings.

```
config={
    "serviceAccount":"abc.json"
}

firebase=pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
storage = firebase.storage()

ab=str(1)    
all_files = storage.child("images").list_files() //Enter the name of the folder    
for file in all_files:            
try:
        print(file.name)    
        z=storage.child(file.name).get_url(None)    
        storage.child(file.name).download(""+path+"/"+ab+".mp3")    
        x=int(ab)     
        ab=str(x+1)    
except:    
        print('Download Failed')
```

Comment: why do i need a service account if i have permission access!
do you know anyway to get over this?

Answer (score 0):

Typically you store paths to uploaded files to Realtime Database or some other data store.  This lets you iterate uploaded files programmatically if you want to make changes to them later.

Alternatively, you can use the [list_blobs()](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/client.html#google.cloud.storage.client.Client.list_blobs) API as shown in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects) for the Cloud Storage python SDK.

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet or a reference, on how can i achieve it

Comment: Hi Doug, there is a (new?) list API for cloud storage https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/list

Comment: @philshem Yes, I believe that's new, but I don't think that's made it down to the admin SDKs yet.

Comment: @philshem Correction - it is in the admin SDKs now (at least node and Java), but they have different method names in different languages.  Don't know about python.

Comment: @DougStevenson why do i need a service account if i have permission access to all the file list!,
is there anyway to get over this?

Answer (score 0):

Pyrebase Storage supports a `list_files()` function. You can use this to loop through all files in a given folder, downloading on each pass with the `download_to_filename()` function.

Something like this:

```
storage = firebase.storage()
datadir = 'path/to/local/directory/'

all_files = storage.child("myfirebasefolder").list_files()

for file in all_files:
    try:
        file.download_to_filename(datadir + file.name)
    except:
        print('Download Failed')
```